# Power set of a subset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Proof that if $A \subseteq B$, then ${\mathscr P}(A) \subseteq {\mathscr P}(B)$.

I tried using the definition of a subset: $A \subseteq B = \forall x(x \in A \to x \in B)$, but get stuck as to how to use it to write the power sets of A and B.

Comment: Use the definitions for $\mathscr P(A)$ as well. Show that if $X\in\mathscr P(A)$ then $X\in\mathscr P(B)$.

Comment: We were given a textual, not a mathematical definition of a power set: "the power set of a set A is the set containing the subsets of A."

Comment: Yes, and that translates to the following: $$\forall x(x\in\mathscr P(A)\leftrightarrow x\subseteq A) $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition of the exercise tells you to consider that $A \subseteq B$. Power set of A is defined as follows: if X is in $\mathscr{P}(A)$, then $X \subseteq A$. But as stated before, $A \subseteq B$, so $X \subseteq B$, too. Thus, as $X \subseteq B$, it follows that X is in $\mathscr{P}(B)$.

If X is in $\mathscr{P}(A)$ implies that X in $\mathscr{P}(B)$, then $\mathscr{P}(A) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$, q.e.d.

Answer (score 2):

Given $X\in {\mathscr P}(A)$ hence $x\in X\implies x\in A$ but we know that $x\in A\implies \cdots$ hence $x\in X\implies \cdots $  as a conclusion $X\in {\mathscr P}(B)$

(Fill in dots)

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with a "naïve" set theoretical proof:

$\scr P(A)$ is nothing but $2^A$, the collection of all maps from $A$ to the two-element set $2$(an element of $A$ is either inside a subset, or outside, represented as two "states").

If $B \subset A$, then an inclusion map $\mathscr P(B) \hookrightarrow \scr P(A)$ can be seen by extension of every map $B \mapsto 2$, by a fixed map $A \setminus B \mapsto 2$, into a map $A \mapsto 2$.

Comment: That is a horrible approach to this problem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Maybe it is not very pedagogical, but is it mathematically wrong?

Comment: Not wrong, but it requires a different set of tools, e.g. looking at "subset" as a function rather than a set which is a subset. So yes, just very not pedagogical.

Comment: There's a natural isomorphism between the power set and the functions to 2,  so there's certainly nothing wrong with looking at it from that angle.  IT's nonstandard,  but certainly not wrong :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila So let it stay there for someone who is having a second look on to elementary set theory, with your warning too being there.